# CSS Content Spills Out of Div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create my first from-scratch webpage in a kind of blog format. My header/feature/sidebar/footer seems to be behaving itself so far but I'm struggling on two points. My Nav Bar links don't want to stay in the nav div and the flex-box within the feature section doesn't want to appear in rows.

The nav bar is the bigger headache so specific help on that one is much appreciated. If you can solve both, even better :)

Thank you!

```css
/* ----------------------------- */


/* BASIC SETUP */


/* ----------------------------- */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  color: rgb(13, 56, 0);
}

html {
  /* background-color: rgb(179, 223, 198); */
  font-family: "Lato", "Arial", sans-serif;
  /* this is the imported font */
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/* ----------------------------- */


/* NAVIGATION */


/* ----------------------------- */

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 55px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-nav li {
  /* this selects all li elements in .main-nav */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
  /* this selects the a tags inside each .main-nav li element */
  padding: 8px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 90%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(13, 56, 0, 0.933);
}

#nav {
  border: 0.5px solid rgb(94, 2, 2);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  grid-area: nav;
}


/* ----------------------------- */


/* MAIN GRID & FLEX */


/* ----------------------------- */

.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 5vh 10vh 70vh 10vh;
  grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav nav" "header header header header" "main main main sidebar" "footer footer footer footer";
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#b1 {
  border: 0.5px solid rgb(94, 2, 2);
  order: 1;
  grid-area: header;
}

#b2 {
  border: 0.5px solid rgb(94, 2, 2);
  order: 2;
  grid-area: main;
}

#b3 {
  border: 0.5px solid rgb(94, 2, 2);
  order: 3;
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

#b4 {
  border: 0.5px solid rgb(94, 2, 2);
  order: 4;
  grid-area: footer;
}


/* ----------------------------- */


/* FEATURE FLEX */


/* ----------------------------- */

.feature {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#f1 {
  order: 1;
}

#f2 {
  order: 2;
}

#f3 {
  order: 3;
}

#f4 {
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Exercise 1</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maxium-scale=1" name="viewport" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;1,300&display=swap" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box" id="nav">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Search</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Archive</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Other</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="b1">This is the Title Page of my Project.</div>
    <div class="box" id="b2">
      <article class="feature" id="f1">One</article>
      <article class="feature" id="f2">Two</article>
      <article class="feature" id="f3">Three</article>
      <article class="feature" id="f4">Four</article>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="b3">
      This will be the right-hand Content column.
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="b4">This is the Footer of my project.</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

</html>
```

Comment: please add a drawing of the intended layout

Comment: PS: you have 2 `<html>` opening and closignt ags which would be an invalid markup.

Answer (score 1):

.main-nav remove margin-top and .box change display to display: flex; This should fix your issues.

Comment: I cannot believe I spent an hour looking at this and didn't notice the 55px margin-top... fml.

Thanks so much Brent!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @BrentOwen answer here is the working snippet.

```css
/* BASIC SETUP */


/* ----------------------------- */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  color: rgb(13, 56, 0);
}

html {
  /* background-color: rgb(179, 223, 198); */
  font-family: "Lato", "Arial", sans-serif;
  /* this is the imported font */
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/* ----------------------------- */


/* NAVIGATION */


/* ----------------------------- */

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-nav li {
  /* this selects all li elements in .main-nav */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
  /* this selects the a tags inside each .main-nav li element */
  padding: 8px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 90%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(13, 56, 0, 0.933);
}

#nav {
  border: 0.5px solid rgb(94, 2, 2);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  grid-area: nav;
}


/* ----------------------------- */


/* MAIN GRID & FLEX */


/* ----------------------------- */

.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 5vh 10vh 70vh 10vh;
  grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav nav" "header header header header" "main main main sidebar" "footer footer footer footer";
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#b1 {
  border: 0.5px solid rgb(94, 2, 2);
  order: 1;
  grid-area: header;
}

#b2 {
  border: 0.5px solid rgb(94, 2, 2);
  order: 2;
  grid-area: main;
}

#b3 {
  border: 0.5px solid rgb(94, 2, 2);
  order: 3;
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

#b4 {
  border: 0.5px solid rgb(94, 2, 2);
  order: 4;
  grid-area: footer;
}


/* ----------------------------- */


/* FEATURE FLEX */


/* ----------------------------- */

.feature {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#f1 {
  order: 1;
}

#f2 {
  order: 2;
}

#f3 {
  order: 3;
}

#f4 {
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Exercise 1</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maxium-scale=1" name="viewport" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;1,300&display=swap" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box" id="nav">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Search</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Archive</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Other</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="b1">This is the Title Page of my Project.</div>
    <div class="box" id="b2">
      <article class="feature" id="f1">One</article>
      <article class="feature" id="f2">Two</article>
      <article class="feature" id="f3">Three</article>
      <article class="feature" id="f4">Four</article>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="b3">
      This will be the right-hand Content column.
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="b4">This is the Footer of my project.</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```